# How to split 2 columns into 4 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that shows me a table with Id, Question, and Reply. I need to split my columns Question and Reply into 4 columns (Q1, R1, Q2, R2). How can I do this with two columns simultaneously? I find answers, that help only with one column to two.

[image]

Comment: Google for SQL pivot query.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       'Q1' as question_1,
       max(case when question = 'Q1' then reply end) as reply1,
       'Q2' as question_2,
       max(case when question = 'Q2' then reply end) as reply2
from t
group by id;
```

EDIT:

You can use the same idea with `row_number()`:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then question end) as question1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then reply end) as reply1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then question end) as question2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then reply end) as reply2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by question) as seqnum
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Maybe I didn't describe the question so accurately. Here above I gave it as an example, but the questions can be completely different, 82036 Q1 != 57529 Q1